# Desmembrando campos da query

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma busca com mysql, onde o retorno é um campo `DATE`, preciso desmembrar este campo em DIA, MES, HORA, SEGUNDOS e colocar cada um dentro de uma variavel, não estou conseguindo fazer isto, tentei fazer por uma query porem esta retornando

> Resource id #18
>
> Resource id #19

A query que fiz é a seguinte:

```
SELECT DATE(DAT_EHORA_EVENT) FROM tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA WHERE COD_SEQUN_AGEND = '".$linha['COD_SEQUN_AGEND']."'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solução no `MySQL`

```
SELECT YEAR(DAT_EHORA_EVENT), 
       MONTH(DAT_EHORA_EVENT), 
       DAYOFMONTH(DAT_EHORA_EVENT), 
       HOUR(DAT_EHORA_EVENT), 
       MINUTE(DAT_EHORA_EVENT), 
       SECOND(DAT_EHORA_EVENT)
FROM tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA WHERE COD_SEQUN_AGEND = '".$linha['COD_SEQUN_AGEND']."'
```

#### Solução no `PHP`

```
$hora = strtotime($row["DAT_EHORA_EVENT"]);
echo date('Y', $hora); // ano
echo date('m', $hora); // mês
echo date('d', $hora); // dia
echo date('h', $hora); // hora
echo date('i', $hora); // minuto
echo date('s', $hora); // segundo
```

Comment: E para inverter a data como que faz mesmo ?

Comment: Porque vem YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: Você diz de formatar pra dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: Vem assim porque é a formatação dentro do MySql

Comment: isso, exatamente mais ja conseguir.